# Strings getting converted to null when writing JSON representation of RDD

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to write RDD which is structure like

(int , ListofList , ListofListofList)

Something like this

```
(49807360, [[111206019,'ABC','XYZ:RDC' , 'RDC' , 123] , [111206019,'ABC','XYZ:RDC' , 'RDC' , 123]] , [[[111206019,'ABC','XYZ:RDC' , 'RDC' , 123] , 111206019,'ABC','XYZ:RDC' , 'RDC' , 123]] , [[111206019,'ABC','XYZ:RDC' , 'RDC' , 123],[111206019,'ABC','XYZ:RDC' , 'RDC' , 123]])
```

When I print this is RDD form I see the data correctly. When I used inbuilt library to write it in JSON format I am getting null values in place of strings.

```
{"user":49807360,"history":[[111206019,null,null,null,123], [111206019,null,null,null,123]],"collection":...}
```

The line of code I am using to serialize RDD to JSON is

```py
rdd.toDF().toJSON().saveAsTextFile(ouput_file_path)
```

I have also tried

```py
rdd.toDF().write.json(ouput_file_path,"overwrite","gzip")
```

Above code was run in spark version 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you use `DataFrame` as an intermediate step. Spark SQL doesn't support heterogeneous arrays, so values which don't match inferred type (`array<bigint>`) are replaced by `NULL`.

If you really want to go this way, and support heterogeneous structures, you should use `tuples` which should be mapped to Spark SQL `structs`, or don't depend on schema inference, and provide desired schema explicitly:

```
schema = ...  # type: StructType
spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

with schema ([JSON representation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType.fromJson)) similar to:

```
{'fields': [{'metadata': {}, 'name': '_1', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'long'},
  {'metadata': {},
   'name': '_2',
   'nullable': True,
   'type': {'containsNull': True,
    'elementType': {'fields': [{'metadata': {},
       'name': '_1',
       'nullable': True,
       'type': 'long'},
      {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_2', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
      {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_3', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
      {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_4', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
      {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_5', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'long'}],
     'type': 'struct'},
    'type': 'array'}},
  {'metadata': {},
   'name': '_3',
   'nullable': True,
   'type': {'fields': [{'metadata': {},
      'name': '_1',
      'nullable': True,
      'type': {'fields': [{'metadata': {},
         'name': '_1',
         'nullable': True,
         'type': 'long'},
        {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_2', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
        {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_3', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
        {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_4', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
        {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_5', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'long'}],
       'type': 'struct'}},
     {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_2', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'long'},
     {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_3', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
     {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_4', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
     {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_5', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
     {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_6', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'long'}],
    'type': 'struct'}},
  {'metadata': {},
   'name': '_4',
   'nullable': True,
   'type': {'containsNull': True,
    'elementType': {'fields': [{'metadata': {},
       'name': '_1',
       'nullable': True,
       'type': 'long'},
      {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_2', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
      {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_3', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
      {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_4', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
      {'metadata': {}, 'name': '_5', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'long'}],
     'type': 'struct'},
    'type': 'array'}}],
 'type': 'struct'}
```